# Issues with custom Google Chrome *.desktop file

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, customization, ubuntu-unity, quicklaunch

I've got some issues with a custom *.desktop file for Google's Crome Browser for the Unity Quicklist. I've added some additional shortcuts for example for YouTube. The problem is that if no Chrome Window is opened it adds as I click the YouTube shortcut a new Chrome icon in the quicklist (so I have at least Chrome two times in thee list). If I click on "Open new window" or "open new incongito window" it works as it should and set the custom quicklist shortcut "as active".

The Shortcut Entry:

```
> [YouTube Shortcut Group] 
> Name=YouTube 
> Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome www.youtube.com
> TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

The shortcut Group is listed in the google-chrome.desktop file right after the two standard shortcut groups.

So, what is wrong? Is there any special argument I have to add (besides the '--app=' arg that not really results in a perfect solution)?

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Comment: Are you trying to make changes to the window manager code? If you are just trying to change the configuration settings without changing the code, then you should ask on SuperUser.com, ubuntu.stackexchange.com, or unix.stackexchange.com. StackOverflow is only for programming questions.

Answer (score 2):

[Desktop Entry]

Version=1.0

Name=Google Chrome

GenericName=Web Browser

Comment=Access the Internet

Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome %U --blacklist-accelerated-compositing

Terminal=false

Icon=google-chrome

Type=Application

Categories=Network;WebBrowser;

MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml_xml;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp;

X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=***phpMyAdmin***;NewWindow;NewIncognito

[***phpMyAdmin*** Shortcut Group]

Name=phpMyAdmin

Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome localhost/phpmyadmin

TargetEnvironment=Unity

[NewWindow Shortcut Group]

Name=New Window

Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome

TargetEnvironment=Unity

[NewIncognito Shortcut Group]

Name=New Incognito Window

Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --incognito

TargetEnvironment=Unity

---

This works for me, I had to add the name of the shortcut to X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=